# Install logstash plugin from private gem repository

Tags: plugins, logstash

According to Logstash [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/private-rubygem.html), I updated the Gemfile on my logstash instance to use my private gem repository as source instead of rubygems.org:

```
# This is a Logstash generated Gemfile.
# If you modify this file manually all comments and formatting will be lost.

source "http://my-private-repo/"
```

When running the command to install I get this error:

```
# /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-prune
    Validating logstash-filter-prune
    logstash-filter-prune is not a Logstash plugin
    ERROR: Installation aborted, verification failed for logstash-filter-prune
```

Looking at the logstash-plugin [source code](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/88d6a3d3f4dd92a03dfb356bf12753e6008276ff/lib/pluginmanager/util.rb#L77) I see that it tries to validate that the plugin name has ".gem" in it, but when I add ".gem" to the plugin name it tries to install the plugin from the internet:

```
# /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-prune.gem
Validating logstash-filter-prune.gem
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - Failed to open TCP connection to api.rubygems.org:443 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "api.rubygems.org" port 443) (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Tested on logstash 7.9.3:

```sh
Usage:
    bin/logstash-plugin install [OPTIONS] [PLUGIN] ...

Parameters:
  [PLUGIN] ...       plugin name(s) or file

Options:
  --version VERSION  version of the plugin to install
  --[no-]verify      verify plugin validity before installation (default: true)
  --preserve         preserve current gem options (default: false)
  --development      install all development dependencies of currently installed plugins (default: false)
  --local            force local-only plugin installation. see bin/logstash-plugin package|unpack (default: false)
  -h, --help         print help
```

Try to use:

```sh
logstash-plugin install --no-verify --local /path/to/logstash-filter-prune.gem
```

or

```sh
for gemname in /path/to/logstash-*.gem; do
    [ -e "$gemname" ] || continue
    logstash-plugin install --no-verify --local "/path/to/${gemname}"
done
```